# Why does a variable with .substring() not reflect css styling?

Tags: javascript

Using pure javascript, I am trying to create a price-validating function that when used, validates prices entered into a form. There are 4 requirements to my validation:

1. Input must be a number and cannot be empty
2. If a decimal is entered, there must at least be 1 pre- and post-decimal character
3. Price entered must be a number that is between $1 and $99.99 (both inclusive)
4. Price entered must not have whitespaces in between

and here is my code:

```js
function formCheck() {
  var success = true; //default, assumes client enters all fields correctly so "process.html" will load
  var msgBox = document.getElementById('divMessage'); //feedback div

  //Price Variables
  var movPrice = document.getElementById('txtPrice');
  var priceFdBk1 = '<ul><li> Please enter <b>numbers</b> only. </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk2 =
    '<ul><li> You entered a decimal point. Please enter a <b>number</b> both before and after the decimal place. </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk3 = '<ul><li> Please enter a movie price between $1.00 to $99.99 (up to 2 decimal places). </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk4 = '<ul><li> Please do not leave a space when entering the movie price. </li></ul>';

  //Price Validation
  function priceCheck(price, fdBk1, fdBk2, fdBk3, fdBk4) {
    //arguments = price and feedbacks if errors are made
    var price_clean = price.value.trim(); //price entered by client without whitespace
    var price_len = price_clean.length; //number of characters in price entered

    //If there is a $ sign, remove it first
    var dollarSensor = price_clean.charAt(0);
    if (dollarSensor == '$') {
      price_clean = price_clean.substring(1);
    }

    //If there is a decimal point, obtain pre- and post-decimal characters
    if (price_clean.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      var deciSensor = 1; //remember that input has a decimal
      var intValue = price_clean.split('.')[0]; //obtain pre-decimal characters)
      var decimalValue = price_clean.split('.')[1]; //obtain post-decimal characters
      var postCounter = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < decimalValue.length; j++) {
        //count number of decimal places
        postCounter += 1;
      }
    }

    //Filter 1: Input must be a number and cannot be empty
    if (isNaN(price_clean) || price_clean == '') {
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk1;
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false;
    }

    //Filter 2: If a decimal is entered, there must at least be 1 pre- and post-decimal character
    else if ((deciSensor == 1 && intValue == '') || (deciSensor == 1 && decimalValue == '')) {
      //if client did not enter a number before and after the decimal point
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk2;
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false;
    }

    //Filter 3: Price entered must be a number that is between $1 and $99.99 (both inclusive)
    else if (price_clean < 1 || price_clean > 99.99 || postCounter > 2) {
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk3; //message in feedback div
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
    } else {
      price.className = 'transparent';
    }

    //Filter 4: Price entered must not have whitespaces in between
    for (var i = 0; i < price_len; i++) {
      oneDigit = price_clean.charAt(i);
      if (oneDigit == ' ') {
        //if the price float character has a whitespace
        msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk4; //message in feedback div
        price.className = 'yellow'; //highlight error in client's input
        success = false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
      } else if (oneDigit == '') {
        //if the price float character has no whitespace
        price.className = 'transparent'; //remove highlight from client's input
      }
    }
  }
  priceCheck(movPrice, priceFdBk1, priceFdBk2, priceFdBk3, priceFdBk4);

  return success;
}
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

h1 {
  color: #7157ff;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #f90;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 70%;
}

#div_main {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

#div_left {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#div_left p {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}

#div_right {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_main">
  <h1>
    Add Movie
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="process.html" method="POST">
    <div id="div_left">
      <p>Price* ($):</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
      <p><input type="text" id="txtPrice" name="txtPrice"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return formCheck()">
  </form>
  <div id="divMessage">
    *denotes compulsary fields.
  </div>
</div>
```

The code works fine but has 1 issue, which I suspect comes from this line:

```
price_clean = price_clean.substring(1)
```

Specifically, whenever I enter a "$" sign into the form, my code will remove the "$" sign and validate the input as usual. However, when the input is invalid, it no longer highlights the input box in yellow.

May I know what is going on and how can this be fixed using vanilla javascript? Thank you

Comment: btw, why not use regex for checking?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As you might have suspected, this is for an assignment and regex is not allowed.

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" max="99.99" step="0.01" />`

Comment: Don't class directly to the variable, assign the class (depending on the result) to the Id of the div / input where the output is going to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're adding the yellow highlight, but then removing it in your final for loop, this is due to your final for loop using `price_len`, which is calculated *before* you remove the `$`. As a result, your for loop is doing one additional iteration, and so `.charAt(i)` tries to access an index not in your string giving you an empty string. To fix this, you can calculate the length after you've removed the additional `$`:

```js
function formCheck() {
  var success = true; //default, assumes client enters all fields correctly so "process.html" will load
  var msgBox = document.getElementById('divMessage'); //feedback div

  //Price Variables
  var movPrice = document.getElementById('txtPrice');
  var priceFdBk1 = '<ul><li> Please enter <b>numbers</b> only. </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk2 =
    '<ul><li> You entered a decimal point. Please enter a <b>number</b> both before and after the decimal place. </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk3 = '<ul><li> Please enter a movie price between $1.00 to $99.99 (up to 2 decimal places). </li></ul>';
  var priceFdBk4 = '<ul><li> Please do not leave a space when entering the movie price. </li></ul>';

  //Price Validation
  function priceCheck(price, fdBk1, fdBk2, fdBk3, fdBk4) {
    //arguments = price and feedbacks if errors are made
    var price_clean = price.value.trim(); //price entered by client without whitespace
    

    //If there is a $ sign, remove it first
    var dollarSensor = price_clean.charAt(0);
    if (dollarSensor == '$') {
      price_clean = price_clean.substring(1);
    }

    var price_len = price_clean.length; //number of characters in price entered
    //If there is a decimal point, obtain pre- and post-decimal characters
    if (price_clean.indexOf('.') > -1) {
      var deciSensor = 1; //remember that input has a decimal
      var intValue = price_clean.split('.')[0]; //obtain pre-decimal characters)
      var decimalValue = price_clean.split('.')[1]; //obtain post-decimal characters
      var postCounter = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < decimalValue.length; j++) {
        //count number of decimal places
        postCounter += 1;
      }
    }

    //Filter 1: Input must be a number and cannot be empty
    if (isNaN(price_clean) || price_clean == '') {
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk1;
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false;
    }

    //Filter 2: If a decimal is entered, there must at least be 1 pre- and post-decimal character
    else if ((deciSensor == 1 && intValue == '') || (deciSensor == 1 && decimalValue == '')) {
      //if client did not enter a number before and after the decimal point
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk2;
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false;
    }

    //Filter 3: Price entered must be a number that is between $1 and $99.99 (both inclusive)
    else if (price_clean < 1 || price_clean > 99.99 || postCounter > 2) {
      msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk3; //message in feedback div
      price.className = 'yellow';
      success = false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
    } else {
      price.className = 'transparent';
    }

    //Filter 4: Price entered must not have whitespaces in between
    for (var i = 0; i < price_len; i++) {
      oneDigit = price_clean.charAt(i);
      if (oneDigit == ' ') {
        //if the price float character has a whitespace
        msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk4; //message in feedback div
        price.className = 'yellow'; //highlight error in client's input
        success = false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
      } else if (oneDigit == '') {
        //if the price float character has no whitespace
        price.className = 'transparent'; //remove highlight from client's input
      }
    }
  }
  priceCheck(movPrice, priceFdBk1, priceFdBk2, priceFdBk3, priceFdBk4);

  return success;
}
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}

h1 {
  color: #7157ff;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid #f90;
  padding: 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 70%;
}

#div_main {
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 500px;
}

#div_left {
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#div_left p {
  margin-bottom: 19px;
}

#div_right {
  width: 350px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_main">
  <h1>
    Add Movie
  </h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="process.html" method="POST">
    <div id="div_left">
      <p>Price* ($):</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
      <p><input type="text" id="txtPrice" name="txtPrice"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return formCheck()">
  </form>
  <div id="divMessage">
    *denotes compulsary fields.
  </div>
</div>
```

There are however a few improvements you can consider making to your code though:

1. Use `const` or `let` instead of `var` (to help with minimizing scoping issues)
2. Update your code to use [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) to remove/add your highlight class
3. Consider using regular expressions or HTML5 validation with custom validation messages using [`setCustomValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API%27s_element.setCustomValidity())
4. Use DOM2 event hanlders by using [`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) instead of DOM0 (onxyz) HTML attributes

Answer (score 1):

A small fix to your code, you've set price_len before removing leading `$`

```
   const price_len = price_clean.length;
   for(var i=0; i<price_len; i++){
     ...
   }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style> 
        .yellow{
            background-color:yellow
        }

    .transparent{
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #7157ff;
    }

    hr {
        display: block;
        border: 0;
        border-top: 3px solid #f90;
        padding: 0; 
    }
    
    textarea {
        width: 70%;
    }
    
    #div_main {
        font-family: Sans-serif;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 30px;
        width: 500px;
    }
    
    #div_left {
        width: 150px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
    
    #div_left p {
        margin-bottom: 19px;
    }
    
    #div_right {
        width: 350px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
    </style>

    <script language="javascript">
        function formCheck(){
        var success=true; //default, assumes client enters all fields correctly so "process.html" will load
        var msgBox = document.getElementById("divMessage"); //feedback div
    
    //Price Variables
        var movPrice = document.getElementById("txtPrice");
        var priceFdBk1 = "<ul><li> Please enter <b>numbers</b> only. </li></ul>"
        var priceFdBk2 = "<ul><li> You entered a decimal point. Please enter a <b>number</b> both before and after the decimal place. </li></ul>"
        var priceFdBk3 = "<ul><li> Please enter a movie price between $1.00 to $99.99 (up to 2 decimal places). </li></ul>"
        var priceFdBk4 = "<ul><li> Please do not leave a space when entering the movie price. </li></ul>"

    //Price Validation
    function priceCheck(price,fdBk1,fdBk2,fdBk3,fdBk4){ //arguments = price and feedbacks if errors are made
        var price_clean = price.value.trim(); //price entered by client without whitespace
        //var price_len = price_clean.length; //number of characters in price entered

        //If there is a $ sign, remove it first
        var dollarSensor = price_clean.charAt(0);
        if (dollarSensor=="$"){
            price_clean = price_clean.substring(1);
        }            
        
        //If there is a decimal point, obtain pre- and post-decimal characters
        if (price_clean.indexOf('.')>-1){
            var deciSensor=1 //remember that input has a decimal          
            var intValue = price_clean.split(".")[0]; //obtain pre-decimal characters)
            var decimalValue = price_clean.split(".")[1]; //obtain post-decimal characters
            var postCounter=0
            for (var j=0;j<decimalValue.length;j++){ //count number of decimal places
                postCounter+=1;
            }
        }
    
        //Filter 1: Input must be a number and cannot be empty      
        if (isNaN(price_clean)||price_clean==""){
            msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk1;
            price.className="yellow";
            success=false;
        }

        //Filter 2: If a decimal is entered, there must at least be 1 pre- and post-decimal character          
        else if (deciSensor==1 && intValue==""||deciSensor==1 && decimalValue==""){ //if client did not enter a number before and after the decimal point
            msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk2;
            price.className="yellow";
            success=false;
        }

        //Filter 3: Price entered must be a number that is between $1 and $99.99 (both inclusive)
        else if (price_clean<1||price_clean>99.99||postCounter>2){
                msgBox.innerHTML = fdBk3; //message in feedback div
                price.className="yellow";
                success=false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
        }

        else{
            price.className="transparent";
        }

        //Filter 4: Price entered must not have whitespaces in between
        const price_len = price_clean.length;
        for(var i=0; i<price_len; i++){
            oneDigit = price_clean.charAt(i);
            if (oneDigit==" "){ //if the price float character has a whitespace
                msgBox.innerHTML= fdBk4; //message in feedback div
                price.className="yellow"; //highlight error in client's input
                success=false; //prevent loading of "process.html" since selected movie is invalid
            }
            else if (oneDigit==""){ //if the price float character has no whitespace
                price.className="transparent"; //remove highlight from client's input
            }
        }
    }
    priceCheck(movPrice,priceFdBk1,priceFdBk2,priceFdBk3,priceFdBk4)
    return success;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div_main">
    <h1>
        Add Movie
    </h1>
    <hr>
    <form action="process.html" method="POST">
    <div id="div_left">
        <p>Price* ($):</p>
    </div>
    <div id="div_right">
        <p><input type="text" id="txtPrice" name="txtPrice"></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" onclick="return formCheck()">
    </form>
    <div id="divMessage">
        *denotes compulsary fields.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```